# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value from XIB file

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xib

```
Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Hello everyone, I'm making an app that functions like a "To-Do List" app. However I've made two XIBs for my two custom cells that I want displayed on my TableView.

Keep in mind this is my first time using XIBs and building something that's not been a follow along. I've watched many "To-Do List" projects to get an idea of how this should work so I feel as if I'm on the right path. Anyways, to the code.

My prepare for segue func that is giving the error after putting text into the box :

```
var card: Card?
        
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
        
            let taskText = card!.taskCell.taskText.text
            let taskBtn = card!.taskCell.taskBtn.isSelected
            
            let gratefulText = card!.gratefulCell.gratefulText.text
            let gratefulNum = card!.gratefulCell.gratefulNum.text
            
        card = Card(taskText: taskText!, taskBtn: taskBtn, gratefulText: gratefulText!, gratefulNum: gratefulNum!)
    }
```

Here is my "Card" struct:

```
struct Card: Equatable {
    
    let gratefulCell = GratefulCell()
    let taskCell = TaskCell()
    
    var id = UUID()
    var taskText: String
    var taskBtn: Bool
    
    var gratefulText: String
    var gratefulNum: String
    
    static let dueDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }()
    
    static func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    static func loadTasks() -> [Card]?  {
        return nil
    }
    
    static func loadSampleTasks() -> [Card]? {
        
        let task1 = Card(taskText: "Test", taskBtn: false, gratefulText: "Test", gratefulNum: "1")
        let task2 = Card(taskText: "Test2", taskBtn: false, gratefulText: "Test2", gratefulNum: "2")
        
        
        return [task1, task2]
    }
}
```

Also here is the XIB file in which I'm trying to access the .text on:

```
class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var taskBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var taskText: UITextField!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
//        updateSaveButtonState()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
//        updateSaveButtonState()
    }
    
    @IBAction func isCompleteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        taskBtn.isSelected.toggle()
    }

}
```

If there's any other information I can provide please let me know! Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you are attempting to force unwrap the optional value `card` before any solid value was assigned to it. The only obvious spot where an attempt to assign a value to `card` was made is directly after you've attempted to force unwrap it, which I didn't quite understand, was that intentional?

Comment: @AgentBilly It's making me force unwrap since I made Card optional. However if I keep it optional then force when I assign to `card` it still gives the same error. I an providing text into the textfield so it's not empty whenever I hit me save button with a segue tied to it.

Comment: it's not about where you force unwrap the optional, force unwrapping it later won't change what's in it, the point is that you as the designer have to make sure that there is a value when you are accessing it. Where is the `prepare(for:sender:)` overridden?

Comment: As AgentBilly points out, your code doesn't make sense.  You start by getting values from your `card` property and end by creating a new `Card` and assigning it to your `card` property.  Even if you make the access to `card` optional you will still get a crash because you are force unwrapping properties that you pass to your `Card` initialiser.  These values are going to be `nil` if `card` is `nil`.  A simply rule of thumb with Swift is *never use !*; You can if you know for sure something isn't `nil` (e.g. you just checked for `!=nil`)

Comment: Since this looks like your are handling an unwind segue, do you want to get values from the source view controller (the one you are unwinding from?). If that source view controller has an instance of `Card` you can use assign that to `card`.  No need to create a new instance.